# Loopback: Passing ctx object in remotemethods

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I am trying to access the `ctx` object in my remote method.

I have the following code:

```
MyModel.remoteMethod("getdetails", {
    accepts: [
        { arg: "options", type: "object", http: "optionsFromRequest" }
    ],
    http: {
        path: "/getdetails",
        verb: "get"
    },
    returns: {
        arg: "body",
        type: "object",
        root: true
    }
});
MyModel.getdetails= function( options, cb) {
   console.log(options.ctx);
};
```

I have added `{ arg: "options", type: "object", http: "optionsFromRequest" }` but still I am not getting the `ctx` in my options. `options` contain only the `accessToken` and `authorizedRules`.

How can get access to ctx in remote methods? I am using loopback3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    accepts: [
    {arg: 'ctx', type: 'object', http: {source: 'context'}},
    ...
```